# sine wave model of temperature given daily high and low

Tags: r, weather, trigonometry

I am trying to create a model of daily temperatures that uses the sine wave, along with the daily high and low temperature in R (where the daily high and low change each day). It would look like the sine wave found here: http://www.ipm.ucdavis.edu/WEATHER/ddconcepts.html, under **degree-days**.

The idea will be to calculate the area under the curve found between a high and low threshold.

I have been working on this for longer than I care to admit but don't even have anything worth showing at this point. I am at square one and will take any advice you have.

Comment: For sine graphs, the amplitude is the amount that the graph goes up and down from the _midline_. In other words, the largest difference between values is twice the amplitude.

Comment: Thanks. So then the amplitude for each day would be the difference between the max and min temperature, divided by 2 if I understand that correctly. But how do I make the amplitude different for each day?

Comment: You could make a table of all the maxes and a table for all the mins. Assuming you have 1 high and 1 low per day, you could simply set the unique amplitude each day in a function. If you wanted it to be smooth you would need to do a little more work